# How do I make my rotate function work?

Tags: javascript, html

So what I'm trying to do is create two functions that each go along with their respective buttons.  The purpose of the function is to make divs containing images rotate through a number images.  When 3 is rotated to the right it leaves the stack of visible images on the page, and when 1 is rotated to the left the same happens.  When 1 is rotated to the right, a new image pops into the visible stack.  I have the basic JavaScript written out, however when I click the buttons nothing happens.  Can anyone help me out with this?  Thank you!!

```
#img1 {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: lightblue;
        height: 70px;
        width: 50px;
        z-index: 5;
        margin: auto;
        right: 45px;
    }

    #img2 {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: lightcoral;
        height: 70px;
        width: 50px;
        z-index: 10;
        left: 70px;
        right: 70px;
        top: 100px;
        margin: auto;
    }

    #img3 {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: lightgreen;
        height: 70px;
        width: 50px;
        z-index: 5;
        margin: auto;
        left: 45px;
    }

#rightArrow {
        position: absolute;
        left: 15px;
        bottom: 45px;
        width: auto;
        font-size: 24px;
        transform: rotate(180deg);

    }

    #rightArrow:hover {
        color: yellow;
    }

    #leftArrow {
        position: absolute;
        right: 15px;
        bottom: 45px;
        width: auto;
        font-size: 24px;
        transform: rotate(180deg);

    }

    #leftArrow:hover {
        color: yellow;
    }

<div>
<p id='leftArrow'>&cularr;</p>
<div id='img1' style="border: 2px solid blue;">1</div>
<div id='img2' style="border: 2px solid red;">2</div>
<div id='img3' style="border: 2px solid green;">3</div>
<p id='rightArrow'>&curarr;</p>
```

```
var myLeftArrow = document.querySelector("#rightArrow");
var myRightArrow = document.querySelector("#leftArrow");

myLeftArrow.addEventListener("click", rotateLeft(), false);

    function rotateLeft()
    {
        var set1 = document.getElementById('img1');
        var set2 = document.getElementById('img2');
        var set3 = document.getElementById('img3');
        set1.id = ('img3');
        set2.id = ('img1');
        set3.id = ('img2');
    }

    myRightArrow.addEventListener("click", rotateRight(), false);

    function rotateRight()
    {
        var set1 = document.getElementById('img1');
        var set2 = document.getElementById('img2');
        var set3 = document.getElementById('img3');
        set1.id = ('img2');
        set2.id = ('img3');
        set3.id = ('img1');
    }
```

Comment: You need to post the rest of the code. If that is all the code, then basically, it does nothing except populate a few vars.

Comment: Is this enough code?

Comment: Changing the `id` of an `img` tag does not change the image it displays. Your rotate functions don't rotate images, they just "rotate" id's on imgae elements.

Comment: Could you explain to me why that is even if the id sets the background image?

Comment: If you are using CSS to put background images on elements, then we seem to be missing some code wouldn't you say? So I'll refer you to my first comment.

Comment: Here's the CSS I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in your even listeners. You were passing `rotateLeft()` and `rotateRight()` when you should have passed them without the parenthesis. See working code below.

```js
var myLeftArrow = document.querySelector("#rightArrow");
var myRightArrow = document.querySelector("#leftArrow");

myLeftArrow.addEventListener("click", rotateLeft, false);

    function rotateLeft()
    {
        var set1 = document.getElementById('img1');
        var set2 = document.getElementById('img2');
        var set3 = document.getElementById('img3');
        set1.id = ('img3');
        set2.id = ('img1');
        set3.id = ('img2');
    }

    myRightArrow.addEventListener("click", rotateRight, false);

    function rotateRight()
    {
        var set1 = document.getElementById('img1');
        var set2 = document.getElementById('img2');
        var set3 = document.getElementById('img3');
        set1.id = ('img2');
        set2.id = ('img3');
        set3.id = ('img1');
    }
```

```css
#img1 {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: lightblue;
        height: 70px;
        width: 50px;
        z-index: 5;
        margin: auto;
        right: 45px;
    }

    #img2 {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: lightcoral;
        height: 70px;
        width: 50px;
        z-index: 10;
        left: 70px;
        right: 70px;
        top: 100px;
        margin: auto;
    }

    #img3 {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: lightgreen;
        height: 70px;
        width: 50px;
        z-index: 5;
        margin: auto;
        left: 45px;
    }

#rightArrow {
        position: absolute;
        left: 15px;
        bottom: 45px;
        width: auto;
        font-size: 24px;
        transform: rotate(180deg);

    }

    #rightArrow:hover {
        color: yellow;
    }

    #leftArrow {
        position: absolute;
        right: 15px;
        bottom: 45px;
        width: auto;
        font-size: 24px;
        transform: rotate(180deg);

    }

    #leftArrow:hover {
        color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<p id='leftArrow'>&cularr;</p>
<div id='img1' style="border: 2px solid blue;">1</div>
<div id='img2' style="border: 2px solid red;">2</div>
<div id='img3' style="border: 2px solid green;">3</div>
<p id='rightArrow'>&curarr;</p>
```